# Configure Ext.Loader to have one file per namespace

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Is there a way to configure `Ext.Loader` in such way so it will handle one file per namespace?
Having one class per file is usually ok, but sometimes it requires to have just to much files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have list of all classes, then you can just add appropriate mappings to `Ext.Loader` like so:

```
Ext.Loader.addBaseUrlClassPathMappings({
    "Namespace.Class": "path/fileName.js"
});
```

If you don't have that kind of list then it's not that straightforward. You can override `Ext.configuration.ux.Inventory.getPath` and do some mappings there. Example code:

```
Ext.define('Ext.configuration.ux.Inventory', {
    override: 'Ext.Inventory',
    getPath: (function () {
        var parent = Ext.Inventory.prototype.getPath;

        return function (className) {
            var result = parent.apply(this, [className]);

            // do mapping here                
            console.log(className + ' -> ' + result);

            return result;
        };
    }())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative - if you've got a "private" class that is only intended to be used by (or in conjunction with) the class it's being created by, you can add multiple `Ext.define` statements to a file, and have multiple classes this way.

This is one way to help group related classes and keep the file clutter down a bit.

The caveat to this is that you can't use `requires` or `uses` to load these classes.